# Ignore Required attribute when saving on edit page

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model class that has a couple of required fields:

```
public class UserMetadata
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password.")]
   public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

On the create view, if I don't give a name and/or password, then the validation summary errors appears. All nice and good. For the edit view, I'm only displaying the 'Name' field - I don't to show the 'Password' field.

When I save my changes on the edit page, the validation summary error appears saying that I must enter a password.

How can I control the validation of the password field, so that for the edit view, it should not bother with it? Or, am I approaching this the wrong way? I still want the 'Name' field validation to work on the edit view.

EDIT:

For my MVC project, I'm using Entity Framework. Thus, I have a 'UserMetadata' class defined so that I can attached things like '[Required]' onto certain fields on the 'User' class (which is in the EDMX file).

I should also explain that I'm using a view model eg 'UserEditViewModel' which has a property 'User' attached to it. So on my post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserEditViewModel inputViewModel)
{

    if(ModelState.IsValid) { inputViewModel.User blah.... }

}
```

Think I rushed a bit when typing this question. Any other missing information you think is important, then please give me a shout.

Cheers.
Jas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ended up doing this in my action method:

```
ModelState.Remove("User.Password");
```

Now my code runs fine, only raising validation errors on the "Name" field, which is what I wanted..

Comment: Thank you very much. You have save a lot of my time.

Comment: Where I should write this. In edit action method or submit action method?

Comment: I placed that code in the `[HttpPost]` action method, which for me is the submit one. Hope that helps. `public ActionResult Edit(UserEditViewModel inputViewModel)`

Answer (score 6):

`ModelState.Remove("User.Password")` did not work for me in MVC 3.

However, the following worked.

Option 1:

```
ModelState.Remove("Password")
```

Option 2:

```
ModelState.Where(m => m.Key == "Password").FirstOrDefault().Value.Errors.Clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using your `UserMetadata` class as a view model, you should be using a different view model per page (view).

e.g.

```
public class UserMetaDataCreate
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and UserMetaDataEdit

```
public class UserMetaDataEdit
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, if the edit view doesn't need password, it shouldn't be in the model anyway.

In your controller,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new UserMetaDataCreate());
}
// and subsequent post actions
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserMetaDataEdit vm)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
        return View(vm);
}
```

Of course, you could go about some inheritance as your models become more complex e.g.

```
public class UserMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And subclass your view models

```
public class UserMetaDataEdit
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class UserMetaDataCreate
{

}
```

But, I'm not sure that makes sense contextually since UserMetaData does semantically include a password.