# MVC5 why include not exists property when submit form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

There is My **Admin** Model:

```
[Required]
public int AdminId { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Password { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name {get; set;}
```

I need user **Login** (not register, so I don't need **Name** property):
So , there is 2 property:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminId)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
```

This is the Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "AdminId, Password", Exclude = "Name")]Admin admin)
{
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //

            }
}
```

But The **ModelState.IsValid** Always return false, tell me **Name** property not exists.
I know I use **[Required]**, but it's only for **register**, not for **login**, I even not add Name property when Login. Why still return false? How Can I fixed it?

**Update 1**

I just add a **another new property**:

```
[Required]
public int WorkPlace { get; set; }
```

But It not be valid by ModelState.IsValid......but Why Name Need?? because of **string** type?

**Update 2**

> Looks like It's a some kind of BUG. because the int type can remove
>   use **Exclude**. but the string type can't ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a bug. Using the `Bind.Exclude` just means even if the property value is posted back, don't set its value in my model. Its used to prevent over posting attacks [as explained in more detail here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). `int` type works in your case because the default value for `int` is `0` so its valid, but for `string` the default is `null` so `[Required]` fails. The best way to handle this is to create a view model that contains only the properties you want to edit

```
public class LogInVM
{
  [Required]
  public int AdminId { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and then post back that model (no `Bind` attribute is required)

```
public ActionResult Index(LogInVM model)
{
  ....
```

Comment: No, I still think it's a design BUG. If allow ``int`` , then must allow ``string`` too, else don't allow all. the design very terrible. I'm use EF6 generate the model. I can't create new model for every action like this....

Comment: No, its not a bug. The default value for `int` is `0`, so it you were to post back a value for `WorkPlace` (say `5`) but used `Bind(Exclude="WorkPlace")] then the value is ignored so it remains as the default (which is `0`). It still has a value therefore it fulfills the `[Required]` validation. A string on the other hand is a reference type and its default is null, which does not fulfill the `[Required]` validation so `ModelState` is invalid. If you were to change `WorkPlace` to `int?` (nullable) then that also would fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your `admin` object is just a parameter.  But your `Admin` View Model requires a Name property.  Your model state is thus correctly invalid when the `Name` property is missing.

Two quick solutions would be :

1. Remove the Required attribute
2. Create a new ViewModel for Login

I'd opt for `2`

**Update**

Actually I didn't know this existed, but you can use ModelState.Remove as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900645/ignore-required-attribute-when-saving-on-edit-page)

Comment: I'm use EF6 Database first generate the model. so let me create a new one I think I can't do this for my every model. that can't be solved the problem.....

Comment: ``ModelState.Remove`` worked fine. but why must use that? that's terrible for me. Why the ``[Bind(Exclude="Name")]`` not working on this case?