# How to omit validations of a model inside a parent model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a parent model ParentModel containing a child model ChildModel1 and ChildModel2.

ChildModel1 contains required data annotation, the ParentModel is used inside a view. They are both in the same form who call the same server action, depending on a boolean indicator i have in the parent model, i want to be able to omit validations of ChildModel1 or ChildModel2 so that the modelState doesn't take them into account.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Without code no one can help you.

Comment: Does this thread help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900645/ignore-required-attribute-when-saving-on-edit-page

Comment: @crunchy yes it's good but i need to call it on each property, do you have a way to apply it on all the object? Thanks, you can answer it and i will check it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your post action just remove each child property individually. If you have more than one or two properties you wish to skip validation I'd move them into another method so as not to clutter up the Post action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AnAction(IndexVM model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Child.ChildProperty1");
    ModelState.Remove("Child.ChildProperty2");

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // put code here
    }

    // carry on 
    return View(model)
}
```